# django model manytomany filter

Tags: python, django, filter

Lets say I have User, Newsletter and Subscription models, Subscription is the mapping table for User and Newsletter, eg. Subscription has foreign key to User and Newsletter

```
class User(models.Model):
  ...

class Newsletter(models.Model):
  ...

class Subscription(models.Model):
  subscriber = models.ForeignKey(User)
  newsletter = models.ForeignKey(Newsletter)
```

How do I get the query set that returns Newsletter that a particular user has subscribed to in a very simple query? I feel there is one, but can't really think of it unless going through multiple statements to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Newsletter.objects.filter(
    id__in=[subscription.newsletter.id for subscription in
            Subscription.objects.filter(subscriber=user)]
```

More readable(and verbose) version:

```
subscriptions = Subscription.objects.filter(subscriber=user) # all subscriptions for a given user

newsletter_ids = [subscription.newsletter.id for subscription in subscriptions]

Newsletter.objects.filter(id__in=newsletter_ids) # answer
```